# Tampermonkey. Как задать переменную 1 раз, чтобы при каждом обновлении страницы она не пересоздавалась?

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

Пишу небольшой парсер для Tampermonkey. Как видно из кода, в конце функции происходит переход на другую страницу, после перезагрузки страницы переменная rate объявляется заново, что очень сильно мешает. Как сделать так, чтобы переменная задавалась только 1 раз при старте функции, и после перехода на след. страницу не приходилось опять вводить курс?

```
var total = [];
var rate = prompt('Курс?', 10);

function parse() {
    var arr = [];
    var name = document.querySelectorAll('p.name span');
    var price = document.querySelectorAll('.pull-left > .price');
    for (var i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
        arr.push(name[i].innerHTML + ' ' + (price[i].innerHTML.slice(1) * rate).toFixed(2) + 'р');
    }
    total = localStorage.getItem('total') + ' ' + arr;
    localStorage.setItem('total', total);
    console.log(localStorage.total);
    document.querySelector('li.next > a').click();
}
```

Comment: Какой-нибудь localStorage не поможет?

Comment: А как правильно её объявить, чтобы она сразу в localStorage упала?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Храните эту переменную в localStorage

```js
var rate = localStorage.getItem('rate');
if (rate === null) {
  rate = prompt('Курс?', 10);
  localStorage.setItem('rate', rate);
}
```

Comment: Работает, благодарю!

Answer (score 0):

Так же, как сделал @Anton Shchyrov, только через тернарный оператор (так чуть меньше кода будет)

```
let rate = localStorage.getItem('rage') !== null ? localStorage.getItem('rate) : prompt('Курс?', 10);
localStorage.setItem('rate', rate);
```